# Url rewrite and forced 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We serve our content via ourdomain.com/folder.

The next iteration of the application is ready to be rolled out in ourdomain.com/folder2.

If a user tried to access ourdomain.com/folder2 directly he would get a 404.

I need a to get a rewrite rule that serves the content of ourdomain.com/folder2 under the url ourdomain.com/folder and gives the 404 for direct access to ourdomain.com/folder2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with mod_rewrite? Can't you just rename the subdirs?

```
mv folder folder.old
mv folder2 folder
```

Comment: Good thinking, but the all the php files in the folder2 points to the same system in the the templates directory, templates/folder2.

Then I would have to edit every single php file.

And once we have version 3 going, the renaming process would have to take place again.

Doing the rewrite is less time consuming once it has been implemented, then I just need to change one character for every version iteration.

Comment: Heh ok, well take this opportunity to learn a valuable lesson: use relative paths. :) Or, at the very least, store the path in a variable so that it only needs to be changed in one place.

Comment: Also, you can symlink folder2 to folder after you rename it -- no editing required.

Comment: Symlinking might do the job. Thank you!